# SCCM 2012 - How to deploy 'invisible' application?

Tags: dependencies, sccm-2012

Hi I haven't attempted dealing with dependencies before so maybe I'm doing it wrong

I want to deploy an application, Dynamics AX 2009, to be visible and optional through software center
This application requires a few other installations.
Microsoft Visual 2005 e.g.

My plan is to make an application for each of these required programs, and add them as dependencies to the Dynamics app.
But when I deploy these applications, I can't make these programs invisible in software center
This means I have 5 different programs visible in software center. But I only want the Dynamics visible and the 4 small dependency programs to just automatically install in the background.

What am I doinng wrong.. is it because I don't even need to deploy the dependencies?

Comment: You nailed it in your comment below.  You can answer your own question on SE.  For dependency mapping, you only need to ensure you have the right content available for the end application, and SCCM will even ensure the content is distributed when you publish the main application.  The Fun part is managing detection and installation of x32/x64 apps...

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to deploy dependent applications to user, just add them as dependencies and check "Auto-Install" checkbox for each dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the link below to deploy the invisable application.
please let me know whether this link is usefull or not, or after this link you are still facing some problem

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg682082.aspx

Comment: It wasn't.
I figured out what to do.. I don't deploy the program at all..
And still add it as a dependency, Configmgr will still Download and install it, even though its not deployed.

I could set the program as 'required install', then I would be able to hide it in software center, but I didn't want it as required, only if the optional program was installed should this also be installed.